# Configuring UART Port to 115200 on Renesas RX130 using Code Generator

Tags: electrical-engineering, digital-communication

Does anyone have insights into configuring UART port on Renesas RX130 microcontroller for a bit rate of 115200? I have successfully configured for a 9600, 19200, and 38400. I can read from the MCU and write to the MCU via terminal programs such as tera term. I am using the code generator available through e2Studio IDE.. I am using Serial Communication Interface SCI1, from which I have configured RXD1 / P30 (Pin 18) and TXD1 / P26 (Pin 20). Note P30 is port 3 bit 0 and P26 is port 2 bit 6.

Below is the MCU package configuration view enter image description here
[image]

Below is Code Generator software component configuration view SCI1 enter image description here
[image]

Has anyone run into similar issues? Thanks for your help!

Note: I am open to exploring Firmware Integration Tool (FIT) to configure UART ports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try typing 115200 for bit rate. I think the drop down accepts edited values. The internal software will configure the registers appropriately.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem!